# Directions for a Game on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, routes, directions

I am creating a small game, I will have some objects on the map and they would be able to move only on roads. I have examined the API however, I think, I need to query a route between two points and the object can go to there using way points? However, from the documentation:

> Use of the Google Directions API is subject to a query limit of 2,500
>   directions requests per day

So I would quickly reach the limits with even a small audience. Is there any work-around this?    Are there any common ways of implementing this behavior for a game? I cannot think of another way then just querying routes for each movement info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what the game strategy is and how directions will be used in the game, but it's 2500 queries per day *from the client browser*, so an easy win is to get each player to do their own directions requests and send the results to your server.

Note that 2500 per day may be split into 600 or so per six hours. 100 requests an hour is about one every forty seconds, so if you can average your client activity to this level you may well be ok.

Comment: It's like a strategy game, the player should be able to direct his troops/units to a place and they should be moving on a road only.